# Having problem with getting surface of this area

Tags: geometry, random-variables, area

So I am solving a task in which it says: in a square, side size is 4, there is an x that represents distance from nearest diagonal. determine F(x).

This is random variable problem so I know that F(x) = P(X<x), I have drawn a sketch and I know what too look for. I need to somehow calculate area which represents al the possible X-es where X< x, and that I need to divide by 16 (area of square), this is my sketch and  don't know how to get the area that i colored in black ->  ( https://imgur.com/a/t1szUBW?fbclid=IwAR1hTo5BoaLZWsz3TRt7cY1399bfL4saK0rg9wMJp8lhGU7D1P1ggbsKJSw ).

This is solution to a problem, but I don't know how we got that. F(X) =
$ x\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2} x^2$
any help is appreciated!

Comment: This question makes no sense.  If $x$ "represents distance from nearest diagonal" then what does $F(x)$ represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've redrawn the required area.  It is as follows.

[image]

As you mentioned, $F(x)$ will be the area of the gray region divided by 16.  If the thickness of the a single segment (out of four congruent segments) of this gray area is $x$, then the hypotenuse of of one of the white right triangles is $4 - 2\sqrt{2} x$,
hence the gray area is given by:

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{Gray Area} &= 4 ( \dfrac{16}{4} - \dfrac{1}{4} (4 - 2 \sqrt{2} x)^2 ) \\
& = 16 - (4 - 2 \sqrt{2} x)^2 \\
& = 16 - (16 - 16 \sqrt{2} x + 8 x^2 )\\
& = 16 \sqrt{2} x - 8 x^2 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Hence,

$F(x) = \sqrt{2} x - \dfrac{1}{2} x^2 = \sqrt{2} x (1 - \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} x )$

Note that $x \in [0, \sqrt{2}]$

Comment: Ok I understand everything perfectly except one part, you have got that hypotenuse of white triangle is 4 - 2sqrt(2) * x, I assume you calulated that by doing this -> ( https://imgur.com/iQtollD ) but how did you know that x = x ?(how did you know that both legs are the same) i know it might be trivial.

Comment: @Petar5, it is an isosceles triangle, both angles are $45°$.

Comment: The distance $c = \dfrac{x}{\sin 45^\circ} = \sqrt{2} x $

Comment: oh yes of course, thank you!